# How to set UITableViewCell Identifier in Xcode 4

Tags: ios, xcode4, identifier

In Xcode 4, I failed to find where to set UITableViewCell's Identifier, can anybody helps me?
Thank you very much.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In code:

```
myTableViewCell.reuseIdentifier = @"CustomIdentifier";
```

In the interface design document (right-click and view image to get a bigger picture):
[image: Image of Xcode 4 showing location of UITableViewCell identifier]

1. Go to the leftmost tab here, the Project navigator.
2. Select the `.xib` file containing your cell design.
3. Select the `UITableViewCell` object within the `.xib`
4. Make sure the rightmost "View" is showing and then go to the 4th-from-left tab, the Attributes inspector.
5. The top box labelled "Identifier" is where you enter your identifier.

Comment: Yeah,I finally find my fault. I use a UIView not a UITableViewCell, that's why I cannot find the Identifier field. Thank you all.

Comment: @MichaelMior Did you set your `@property IBOutlet UITableViewCell` to be `readonly`?

Comment: No. Although that's a fair question to ask. I've made dumber mistakes before :)

Comment: Note that you must create a table view cell in Interface Builder for this to work. Don't create an UIView first and then turn it into UITableViewCell. Create an UITableViewCell straight from the objects library.

Answer (score 1):

When you create a new `UITableViewCell` in an interface document, select it, show Utilities by pressing Cmd+Opt+0. Under the "Attributes" inspector the first object is your identifier.

Comment: I am sorry, but you may mean Xcode 3, I mean Xcode 4. I cannot find identifier you figured out in Xcode 4.

Comment: No, I meant Xcode 4 too. Have you created your UITableViewCell in an interface document?

Comment: It should be there, be more attentive. Open the right view in xcode (utilities) and find property identifier. Before this- open .xib file with your cell and click on it in center view.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the attribute named 'tag', type of NSInteger

Comment: Then how to connect with identifier and tag?

Comment: Sorry for misdirecting. Saw Identifier as id. Read method of 'reuseIdentifier' in UITableViewCell's developer document OR set 'Identifier' attribute in Interface Builder.