# UITableViewcell not reused

Tags: ios, uitableview

Shown below is the code I am using to create the cell. The cell is not being reused. Every time the `cell==nil` is becoming true.

I am setting the identifier correctly in the xib. Please help me.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SRCourseListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    if (cell == nil) {

        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"SRCourseListCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];

    }

    return cell;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

in your SRCourseListCell, add

```
- (NSString *) reuseIdentifier {
  return @"cell";
}
```

or (as you are using nibs maybe the better solution), set the [identifier to "cell" in the inspector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238315/how-to-set-uitableviewcell-identifier-in-xcode-4).

Answer (score 1):

In you "SRCourseListCell.xib", go to ***the Attributes Inspector*** and set "SRCourseListCell" for ***Identifier***.

[image: the Attributes Inspector]

Replace below modified code with your exciting one.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    SRCourseListCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SRCourseListCell"];
    if (cell == nil) 
    {
        NSArray *nib=[[NSBundle mainBundle]loadNibNamed:@"SRCourseListCell" owner:self options:nil];
        cell=[nib objectAtIndex:0];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

When calling xib for custom cell, make sure that **Identifier** for the xib must be same as you are using with:

```
[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"SRCourseListCell"]
```

Answer (score -1):

Using the following code to initialize:

```
    YourTableViewCell *cel = [[YourTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"identifier"];
```