# Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value when loading table view data

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

i have a button and table view when i click on the button the table view will be shown and reload its data as follows:

```
   @IBAction func citybtn(_ sender: Any) {
    if citydrop.isHidden == false{
        citydrop.isHidden = true
    }else {
        let filtered_shifts = myShifts.filter{$0.regionName == regionbtn.titleLabel?.text}
        for shift in filtered_shifts {
            cities.append(shift.cityName)
            citiesid.append(shift.idCity)
        }
        uniqueCity = Array(Set(cities))
        uniqueCityid = Array(Set(citiesid))
        print(uniqueCity)

        citydrop.isHidden = !citydrop.isHidden
        contdurdrop.isHidden=true
        nationalitydrop.isHidden=true
        regiondrop.isHidden=true

        btn=2
        citydrop.isHidden=false

        item = uniqueCity
        citydrop.reloadData()
    }

}
```

when i click on the city button it will always crash and displays this error:

[image]

while noting that i have values in uniqueCity ...

> ["Dammam"]

am doing the same exact thing with another button and its working just fine!

so what is the problem why am getting this error?

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    var cell = DropDownViewCell()

    if (tableView == self.regiondrop){
        cell = regiondrop.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dropdowncell") as! DropDownViewCell
        cell.item.text=item[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }else if (tableView == self.citydrop){
        cell = citydrop.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dropdowncell1") as! DropDownViewCell
        cell.item.text=item[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }else if (tableView == self.contdurdrop){
        cell = contdurdrop.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dropdowncell2") as! DropDownViewCell
        cell.item.text=item[indexPath.row]

        return cell

    }else if (tableView == self.nationalitydrop){
        cell = nationalitydrop.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dropdowncell3") as! DropDownViewCell
        cell.item.text=item[indexPath.row]
        return cell

    }
    return cell

}
```

Comment: did you have that cell added or registered in your tableView?

Comment: @ReinierMelian yes!

Comment: You should create cell variable inside every if condition and use tableview not like citydrop and others

Comment: @PPL how to do that? can you give me an example please?

Comment: let cell = tableview.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! DropDownViewCell

Comment: How can you assign multifier cell identifier to single DropDownViewCell?

Comment: Other thing is you are using same item array in all the conditions

Comment: @PPL this is what am doing: cell = citydrop.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dropdowncell1") as! DropDownViewCell same as you said

Comment: @PPL is it wrong to use the same items array?

Comment: @mrs.bassim Simple question: Here you are trying to reuse cell based on the key(identifier). ie You have to assign the key for the cell. Right? Where did you do that?

Comment: @Mani am doing this: if (tableView == self.regiondrop){
            cell = regiondrop.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "dropdowncell") as! DropDownViewCell
            cell.item.text=item[indexPath.row]
            return cell
            
        }

Comment: @mrs.bassim I think, you are messed up. I'm not asking where you used that key. Where did you assign the identifier for the cell? see this link. It may help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238315/how-to-set-uitableviewcell-identifier-in-xcode-4

Comment: @Mani at the first as         var cell = DropDownViewCell()

Comment: @Mani just posted the whole func

Comment: @PPL just posted the whole func can you please check it?

Comment: @mrs.bassim Did you see that link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7238315/how-to-set-uitableviewcell-identifier-in-xcode-4. Did you got the point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because of the identifier, Please follow this steps:

1. Give the identifier name in resueidentifer property of the cell
2. Ensure the cell is registered with the tableview.
3. Use the same identifier for the cell, as I see in your code that you are using the different identifier but the cell is same, please make it same everywhere for each type of cell.

Comment: how to do 1? and can you give me and example of 3 please?

Comment: If you are using the storyboard or xib when you click on cell there is property in attribute inspector with name identifier put any name there and use that name when you are reusing that cell.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: If you are using the storyboard or xib when you click on cell there is property in attribute inspector with name identifier put any name there and use that name when you are reusing that cell. e.g suppose you have given the identifier name  "DropDownViewCell", then your code is
 let cell:DropDownViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "DropDownViewCell") as! DropDownViewCell.

Answer (score 0):

If you take xib then register your cell in did load or there is problem with `dropdowncell1` identifier take in tableview. Double check identifier.